Binary operation on set with one element
It is a fact that every binary operation defined on a set having exactly one element is both commutative and associative. In terms of mathematical logic, do we say that both commutativity and associativity are true vacuously?

I would say no.; the formal definition is: $\forall x \forall y (x,y \in S \to x \cdot y = y \cdot x)$. Here the two leading universal quantifiers do not preclude the fact that when $S = { a }$, $x$ and $y$ are the same element.

"Vacuously" usually refers to quantifications over the empty set, so I would say that any binary operation on the empty set is vacuously commutative and associative, and any binary operation on a singleton set is trivially commutative and associative.

This is very helpful. Thank you!

In other words, "vacuous" refers to the universal property of the initial object while "trivial" refers to the universal property of the terminal object. Note that this isn't a clear-cut definition, and the two may be conflated sometimes, or even become equivalent (in a category with a zero object).

See also this post
